# How to return Double variable in Kotlin

Tags: sql-server, kotlin

I would like to return the ffTotal after adding up all the value retrieved from the database where the category is "Food". However, I cant seem to return the ffTotal object. The ffTotal in the "return ffTotal" is in red, and the "ffTotal" in the "var ffTotal" is never used. May I know why? Below are my codes:

```
private fun getFoodTotal(fTotal : Double) : Double {
    
    val current = LocalDateTime.now()
    val month = current.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)
    val year = current.get(ChronoField.YEAR)
    val sqlCon = SQLCon()
    var LoggedInUser : String? = intent.getStringExtra("Logged In User")
    connection = sqlCon.connectionClass()!!
    try {
        val sql : String=
            "SELECT SUM(eAmount) as sumFAmount from Expenses where Username = '$LoggedInUser'AND eMonth = '$month' AND eYear = '$year' AND Category = 'Food' GROUP BY eMonth, eYear"
        statement = connection!!.createStatement()
        var rs : ResultSet = statement!!.executeQuery(sql)
        //return ffTotal
        if (rs.next())
        {
            var ffTotal = rs.getDouble("sumFAmount")
        }
        rs.close()
        statement!!.close()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } catch (e: Exception) { Log.e("Error", e.message!!) }

    return ffTotal
}
```

Comment: I don't know Kotlin, but that code looks like it's using injection, not parametrisation with syntax like `Username = '$LoggedInUser'`. If so, you have a major security vulnerability. (A quick [Google](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/kotlin-sql-injection-guide-examples-and-prevention/) suggests you are using injection; you ***NEED*** to address that.)

Answer (score 0):

You declare it inside the try block, so it is only visible inside the try block. Move the return inside the try block and have a separate return inside the catch block (or throw an error). Otherwise, declare it before the try block with some default value (doesn't really make sense, but it's an option).

Comment: Hi, I tried to put the return function inside the try block. But when I do so, I got an error telling me that the function requires a return as well. If that is the case, what should I return outside the try block?

Comment: @BadProgrammer What do you _want_ it to return? The function is declared to return a `Double`, so you either have to return a Double value, or throw an exception. You could re-throw the exception you catch; you could return zero, or some other hard-coded value; or you could return null (after changing the function declaration to return `Double?`). Put yourself in the position of someone _calling_ your method. What would make the most sense to them? (Note that whatever happens you should try to close the ResultSet and Statement; the best way of doing that is often in a `finally` block.)

Comment: "the best way of doing that is often in a finally block" In Kotlin I would prefer https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/use.html